# What's the best VPN service for Ubuntu?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I feel I was real lucky **not** signing up for a year of service with Private Internet Service (PIS)!  I signed up for just a month so I could see how I like the service.  I have 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 on an encrypted harddrive.  It ends up their system would not work for my install.  I had to make an unencrypted partition for the PIS client to work on.  I also would not be able to use OpenVPN.

Does anyone know of a good VPN that works on an encrypted partition, with Ubuntu and uses OpenVPN as it's protocol?

Comment: I think this question is too opinion-based to be answered properly. Maybe a better place to ask would be on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

For a detailed VPN comparison sheet check out this  [vpn comparison chart](https://thatoneprivacysite.net/vpn-comparison-chart/) (the downloadable spreadsheet might be nicer then the web version)

Anything that supports OpenVPN should work well on ubuntu.

I have personally used Private Internet Access on ubuntu which worked quite well however the automatic setup scripts were a little outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers so far.  My opologies if I did not do things right here.  I did manage to get a response back from VPNcritic which I'd like to share.

Hi XXX,

That's an interesting issue we never came across. Our Linux writer advised that upon a bit of research, PIA client is not working well on Ubuntu as of this summer at least, and could not find much information regarding it being caused by encrypted drives or how to get around the problem.

He highly suggests to opt for OpenVPN setup, and not follow PIA's suggestion if you prefer to keep the machine fully encrypted. He also said that for himself, he always opts for OpenVPN versus custom clients from the provider.

Hope this helps!

Thanks Again,
VPNCritic

END

I'll look over postings on reddit and see if I can find a proper provider.